# Refactoring ERB to HAML - Ruby code inside ruby code in one line

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, haml, erb

I have a small question and don't have any idea how to deal with my problem.
I was looking for answer to question but I didn't find anything.

I want to refactor erb to haml.
My question is - how to refactor part of code like this (ruby code inside ruby code in one line):

```
<%%= render partial: '<%= singular_table_name %>', collection: @<%= plural_table_name %>, locals: {f: f} %>
```

http://html2haml.com answer is:

```
<%= render partial: '<%= singular_table_name %>', collection: @#{plural_table_name}, locals: {f: f} %>
```

But I don't think that's good idea...

Answer (score 1):

```
= render partial: singular_table_name, collection: @plural_table_name, locals: {f: f}
```

Comment: Thank you. And one more question. How to refactor:
<%%= form_for :filter, url: admin_<%= index_helper %>_path, html: {method: :get, class: 'filter-form'} do |f| %>

Comment: This should work: `= form_for :filter, url: "admin_#{index_helper}_path, html: { method: :get, class: 'filter-form' } do |f|`

Comment: did this work out for you? Also, consider marking the answer accepted if it properly answered your question.